# What specific membrane adaptations do cells have for saline-rich environs?

Tags: cell-membrane, adaptation, cell-biology

Are the cells of marine animals and flora equipped with special ion exchange pumps to mitigate the effects of a saline-rich environment?

Or have the cell's membranes adapted through structural changes to counter the osmotic forces?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This 1969 Steensland paper](http://mic.sgmjournals.org/content/55/3/325.full.pdf+html) seems to suggest that the membranes of halophiles are stabilized by sodium ions and they rapidly denature at lower-salt conditions (2.2 vs. 4.3 M).  The protein composition of the membrane was generally acidic, stabilized by all the Na<sup>+</sup>.

As far as what the role of the halophile membrane is in sheltering the cell from the high ionic strength solution seems left unsaid.